# Bootstrap dropdown menu disappears on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navbar

I made a navbar that only has a dropdown menu. When I view the site on mobile the dropdown menu disappears and the collapse menu doesn't show up either. Not sure how to fix it.

This is what the menu looks like,

**Closed**
[image]
**Open**[image]

**On Mobile**
[image]

This is the html

```
<div class="navbar navbar-light" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-slide-dropdown">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="cards">NotePail</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-slide-dropdown">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a ui-sref="account">My Account</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="cards">My Sets</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="server/logout">Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

How can I get the menu to appear on mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. simplify your HTML-code [as Lucas Watson advised](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38415736/6263942)
2. make `.navbar-header` and `.navbar-right` floating
3. add CSS for mobile dropdown [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37949563/6263942)

Please check the result. Is it what you want to achieve?

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-header {
    float: left;
  }
  .navbar-right {
    float: right !important;
  }
  
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #000;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #e7e7e7 !important;
    background-image: none;
  }  
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #555;
    background-color: #e7e7e7 !important;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a,
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:hover,
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:focus {
    color: #ccc;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-light" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="cards">NotePail</a>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a ui-sref="account">My Account</a></li>
          <li><a ui-sref="cards">My Sets</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="server/logout">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is you're putting your custom dropdown in the "bs-slide-dropdown" div, which Bootstrap traditionally hides and creates a dropdown of on mobile.

What you can do is either A) [Bootstrap 3 - disable navbar collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535289/bootstrap-3-disable-navbar-collapse)

or B) Simpplify your code to something like the following:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-light" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">

  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="cards">NotePail</a>
  </div>

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a ui-sref="account">My Account</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="cards">My Sets</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="server/logout">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

(You may have to mess around with this to get positioning correct)

Answer (score 0):

Add `navbar-defaul`t or `navbar-inverse` to your `.navbar` div to show the toggle styles then you'll see the mobile toggle button to open the menu. Or write some CSS to style the icon-bars. See [Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default)

**With Default Style Example:**

```css
.navbar.navbar-light {
  background: #1086AD;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top navbar-light" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-slide-dropdown">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="cards">NotePail</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-slide-dropdown">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a ui-sref="account">My Account</a>
            </li>
            <li><a ui-sref="cards">My Sets</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="server/logout">Logout</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Example with your own CSS:

```css
.navbar.navbar-light {
  background: red;
}
.navbar.navbar-light .icon-bar {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-light" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-slide-dropdown">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="cards">NotePail</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-slide-dropdown">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a ui-sref="account">My Account</a>
            </li>
            <li><a ui-sref="cards">My Sets</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="server/logout">Logout</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```